# How can we make our strategy only work on one specific pair?

Tags: pine-script

Hey does anyone know if there is a way in pinescript where we can make our custom strategy only work with a specific pair? and not with every pair.

Let say I only want a simple SMA crossover strategy to only work on AAPL stock on 2 hour timeframe, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This will only plot on ticker `AAPL` on a 2 hour timeframe.

```
//@version=4
study("My Strategy", overlay=true)

mySMA = sma(close, 14)
canPlot = syminfo.ticker == "AAPL" and timeframe.isintraday and timeframe.period == "120"

plot(canPlot ? mySMA : na, "mySMA", color=color.yellow)
```

In case of a strategy, you can `AND` this condition to your entry/exit signals.